# Unable to open document from Drop off library in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sql-server, content-database, rbs

Unable to view documents from drop of library it showing error message

When I open pdf documents from a web application, I found below error in uls logs

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Cannot open file
>   "DropOffLibrary/ .pdf".    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAsStream(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Boolean bHonorLevel, Byte iLevel,
>   OpenBinaryFlags grfob, String bstrEtagNotMatch, UInt32&
>   pdwVirusCheckStatus, String& pVirusCheckMessage, String& pEtagNew,
>   String& pContentTagNew)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAsStream(String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Boolean bHonorLevel, Byte iLevel,
>   OpenBinaryFlags grfob, String bstrEtagNotMatch, UInt32&
>   pdwVirusCheckStatus, String& pVirusCheckMessage, String& pEtagNew,
>   String& pContentTagNew) this web application configured content
>   organizer and created with  record center template.

we uploaded some documents to dropof library and can not open and download these documents from browser and this web application configured with RBS in sqlserver

and below error in event viewer for RBS store:

Message ID:21, Level:ERR , Process:1220, Thread:37
Blob store  threw this exception:
Operation: Unknown
BlobStoreId: 2
Log Time: 2/5/2016 4:00:27 PM
Exception: Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.BlobStoreException: This operation failed. See the included exception for more information. ---> System.IO.IOException: The network name cannot be found.

at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at EMC.SourceOne.RBSProvider.ProviderLibrary.RemoteBlobStore.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__13()
   at EMC.SourceOne.RBSProvider.ProviderLibrary.StorageSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(Impersonation impersonation, CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
   at EMC.SourceOne.RBSProvider.ProviderLibrary.RemoteBlobStore.ReadBlob(Byte[] storePoolId, Byte[] storeBlobId)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at EMC.SourceOne.RBSProvider.ProviderLibrary.RemoteBlobStore.ReadBlob(Byte[] storePoolId, Byte[] storeBlobId)
   at Microsoft.Data.BlobStores.BlobStore.ReadBlobInternal(Request request)
BlobStoreException Code: OperationFailedAuthoritative

Comment: You say you are trying to open the documents from a web application, do you mean from a custom App?  Have you tried to open them the browser directly?

Comment: directly from browser